# When I create or update the (belongs_to) model and auto-sync update column in (has_many) model in ember data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, reload

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.0 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

My model like this:

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend
  lists: DS.hasMany('list', async: true)
  total: DS.attr 'number'


App.List = DS.Model.extend
  order: DS.belongsTo 'order'
  price: DS.attr 'number'
  number: DS.attr 'number'
  totalPrice: DS.attr 'number'
```

and the Order show Route:

```
App.OrderRoute = Em.Route.extend

  model: (params)->
    @store.find 'order', params.order_id
```

I can create and update the list in the order show page, when I create a list like this:

```
new_list = @store.createRecord('list', {"price": 5, "number": 1})
  new_list.save().then (model) =>
    @content.get('lists').pushObject model
```

The totalPrice is `price` * `number` but it calculate in the server, so create will return `totalPrice` from the server.

But the `Order` column `total` is plus all the `List` column `totalPrice`, so when I create the `List` my server will update `Order` `total`, but my web side could not see anythings were update. I must refresh the page will see the `total` update.

So, my first problem is:

```
  How can use ember data to reload the Order total when the List is created?
```

And then when I update the list what is I create, the code like this:

Order show templates

```
  {{#each lists itemController='list'}}
    {{input type="text" value=price class="form-control"}}
    {{input type="text" value=number class="form-control"}}
    <a href="#" {{action 'editList'}} class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
      edit
    </a>
  {{/each}}
```

List Controller:

```
  editList: ->
    @content.set('price', @get('price'))
    @content.set('number', @get('number'))
    @content.save().then( (list)=>
      return list
    , ()->
      alert 'Wrong!'
    )
```

Nothing return in the server, when the `list` is update, and my problem is:

```
  How can use ember data to reload the List totalPrice when the List is update? Because the totalPrice to calculate in the server.
```

I think all the problems can use the `ember data` `reload()` or use `ember` `observes`, but I don't know how to use them is the best way. Or have a convenient way to solve the problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to use computed properties. That might solve this issue.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: I want to calculate in server.And how to use compute properties in between in the two model?